Soft Keyboard Overlaps Input in Android WebView but Not in Chrome (DotNet MAUI App)
I'm developing a .NET MAUI app with a WebView that displays my web app. On Android, when the soft keyboard opens, it overlaps input fields instead of panning the content upward (while it does it fine on the Chrome mobile browser).
I’ve tried setting android:Application.WindowSoftInputModeAdjust="Pan" in the App.xaml file, but it doesn’t seem to have any effect on the WebView. On the other hand, using WindowSoftInputModeAdjust="Resize" works, but I specifically want the panning behavior.
How can I achieve "pan" behavior for the soft keyboard in my MAUI app's WebView on Android?
App.Xaml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Application xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp.Mobile"
             xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Controls"
             android:Application.WindowSoftInputModeAdjust="Pan"
             x:Class="MyApp.Mobile.App">
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>

Any guidance would be appreciated!

With Resize your problem is solved which you have with Pan, but you want Pan. Sounds strange

@SirRufo resize is just terrible aesthetically.

@H.A.H. pan may have a terrible user experience (if menu, back or ok button at the top are out of sight)
